# I am expecting the output to be 40 but i got 30

Tags: java, operators

```
class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        byte b=10;
        b +=(b<127)?b>-128? b+=10 :0 :5;
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

i know that the conditions are evaluated `true` and took the control to `b+=10`
so now logically `b+=b+=10;` is adding the value of b and 10 which evaluates 20, assigning to b. Now i'm unable to evaluate it further.

Comment: please format your code more clearly, see above how I've done it

Comment: What is going on it that statement? You have 2 assignments in the same line...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "a^=b^=a^=b;" different from "a^=b; b^=a; a^=b;"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044163/why-is-a-b-a-b-different-from-a-b-b-a-a-b)

Comment: The left hand side is evaluated first, so that's `10`, and then the right hand side, which is `(10 + 10) = 20`, and then the right hand side gets added to the left hand side and stored again in `b`, so that's `10+20 = 30`

Comment: thnks.... @ErwinBolwidt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JLS 15.7.1. Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1) has a similar example :

> If the operator is a compound-assignment operator (§15.26.2), then **evaluation of the left-hand operand includes** both **remembering the variable that the left-hand operand denotes** and **fetching and saving that variable's value for use in the implied binary operation**.
>
> Example 15.7.1-2. Implicit Left-Hand Operand In Operator Of Compound Assigment
>
> In the following program, **the two assignment statements both fetch and remember the value of the left-hand operand**, which is 9, **before the right-hand operand of the addition operator is evaluated**, at which point the variable is set to 3.

```
class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 9;
        a += (a = 3);  // first example
        System.out.println(a);
        int b = 9;
        b = b + (b = 3);  // second example
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

> This program produces the output:

```
12
12
```

Therefore, in your case, the original value of `b` (10) is remembered and added to the result of the ternary conditional operator (which is 20, since the value of `b+=10` is the result of that expression), giving you 30.

Answer (score 1):

First `(b<127)` is evaluated which is `true` so it moves to part `b>-128? b+=10`
In this `b>-128` is evaluated which is also `true` so it moves to `b+=10` which makes b=20 and adds to the left side of expression in which value of 10 is stored in b.So `b+=(b=20)` makes `b=30`

Comment: If this were the case, then b=20 makes b equal to twenty, and then `b += (b=20)` would make it 40. The crucial step is that the very first thing that is done is that the original value of b is saved (10), and that the compound assignment operator adds the value of the right side of the expression to the original saved value of the left side.