# async/await conversion to Promise.resolve and then

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I'm doing a little thought experiment about async/await with non-thenable values. Here, I have some code. I'm having trouble understanding why the output is 1 and then 2. Is it because when I invoke my asynchronous function `increment()`, the functionality inside gets wrapped in a `Promise`? I think I might get a better understanding if I could write this as without async/await and with Promises instead, but I'm not sure where to start.

```js
let num = 0;

async function increment() {
    num += await 2;
    console.log(num);
}
increment();
num+=1;
console.log(num);

//1
//2
```

According to MDN, `async` functions return a `Promise` that is resolved to the value returned by the `async` function. Expressions in front of `await` that are not thenables are wrapped inside of a `Promise.resolve` and subsequent code gets wrapped in a `then()`. By looking at my exercise, I see that my `async` function does not feature a hard coded `return` but it does have an `await`. Since the `await` is followed by a non-thenable, I believe it should wrap that expression in a `Promise.resolve`, so it would be `Promise.resolve(2)`. I thought my code block below would work at first but clearly the fulfilled value of the promise does not get added the way I want it to.

```js
let num = 0;

function increment() {
    num += Promise.resolve(2).then((value) => value).then((value) => console.log(value));
}
increment();
num+=1;
console.log(num);
```

Comment: Related: [Async function with +=](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59802441) - see [Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59802672) in particular.

Answer (score 4):

Your explanation is mostly right. The only problem is the

```
num +=
```

part *outside* of the asynchronous `.then`s. `.then` returns a Promise, not a value, so no matter what's on the right side of this:

```
num += Promise.resolve(2).then( ... ...
```

the result will be using the `+` operator on a Promise, which doesn't make sense.

What the first snippet does

```
num += await 2;
console.log(num);
```

is it waits a Promise that resolves to 2 to fulfill, and then it increments `num` with that value. Similarly, when using `Promise.resolve`, you need to put the increment action inside of the `.then`.

Another complication is `+=` with `await`. When the line is first encountered, the value on the left (the existing variable) is essentially cached as the async action takes place. Then that cached value is retrieved when the async action completes, and added with the result. So, to replicate that, you'll need to store the current value of `num` in another variable first (otherwise you'd see it as 1, instead of 0, due to the `num += 1` below).

(also, `.then(value => value)` is completely superfluous and may be removed)

```js
let num = 0;

function increment() {
    const currNum = num;
    Promise.resolve(2).then((value) => {
        num = currNum + value;
        console.log(num);
    });
}
increment();
num+=1;
console.log(num);
```

Comment: Wow thank you for the explanation. And your snippet with the Promises version makes a lot of sense with mimicking the behavior of async/await. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50870304/18327650

Here's an article about the assignment operator that goes into detail what it does under the hood!